# dpdk-pdump failed in bnx2x_common_dev_init()

Tags: dpdk

I'm trying to use dpdk-pdump with dpdk-stable-18.02.1.

my configurations:

```
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_BNX2X_PMD=y
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_BNX2X_DEBUG_RX=y
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_BNX2X_DEBUG_TX=y
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_BNX2X_MF_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_BNX2X_DEBUG_PERIODIC=y
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_PCAP=y
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PDUMP=y
```

bind the device to DPDK:

```
 Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:03:00.1 'NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet 168e' drv=igb_uio unused=vfio-pci
```

And I start the primary process first:

```
# ./testpmd -c 3 -n 4 -- -i --total-num-mbufs=16384 --port-topology=chained
EAL: Detected 32 lcore(s)
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/.rte_unix
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 14e4:168e net_bnx2x
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 14e4:168e net_bnx2x
Interactive-mode selected
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mbuf_pool_socket_0>: n=16384, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
rte_mempool_ops_get_capabilities: Function not supported
rte_mempool_ops_register_memory_area: Function not supported
[...]
Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
PMD: bnx2x_interrupt_action(): Interrupt handled
PMD: bnx2x_interrupt_action(): Interrupt handled
PMD: bnx2x_interrupt_action(): Interrupt handled
Port 0: C4:34:6B:B0:EA:64
Checking link statuses...
Done
PMD: bnx2x_interrupt_action(): Interrupt handled
testpmd>
```

However, the secondary pdump process failed.

```
# ./dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=*,rx-dev=./capture.pcap'
EAL: Detected 32 lcore(s)
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/.rte_unix_14636_fe8ed726aadaf
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: WARNING: Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) is enabled in the kernel.
EAL:    This may cause issues with mapping memory into secondary processes
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 14e4:168e net_bnx2x
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 14e4:168e net_bnx2x
dpdk-pdump: /root/dpdk-stable-18.02.1/drivers/net/bnx2x/bnx2x_ethdev.c:563: bnx2x_common_dev_init: Assertion `sc->bar[0].base_addr' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Have I missed something? Please give me some information to understand this issue.

Comment: Are you able to send and receive packets with testpmd correctly? Have you tried to disable ASLR?

Comment: Seems that bnx2x doesn't support multi-process. However, I am curious that is there any way to run dpdk-pdump with primary process only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that I can run dpdk-pdump with ixgbe driver.

After comparing `bnx2x_ethdev.c` and `ixgbe_ethdev.c`, I found that bnx2x doesn't support multi-process:

https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/overview.html

Since dpdk-pdump runs as a secondary process, it seems that it is not able to run with bnx2x.

Comment: That table doesn't mention support for multiprocessing, it indicates whether NIC drivers are *aware* of multiprocessing; I don't think that's the same thing. My card's driver (mlx4) is not multiprocess aware, but starting a secondary process works fine!

Comment: Thanks for your information! Did you edit any code or configurations for mlx4? BTW, the multiprocess aware feature is mentioned [here](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/features.html). I thought it should be the same thing? I also took a look at `drivers/net/mlx4` and I didn't find something like `if (rte_eal_process_type() != RTE_PROC_PRIMARY)`. Since it appears in other multiprocess aware drivers, I wonder how it works in your case?

Comment: You're right, that documentation looks clear: multiprocess aware should mean it supports running with a secondary process. Nevertheless, I'm using Mellanox' mlx4 driver with no modifications and was able to run primary/secondary processes as recently as this weekend. Could be a mistake in the table. I don't understand why sharing memory pages with the secondary process would require driver support though. Maybe it's worth raising the issue on the mailing list?